# Actionscript 2 Scope

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Scene 1 - Layer 1

```
import mx.xpath.XPathAPI;
fscommand2("SetQuality", "high");
var apipath = 'http://www.example.net/api/xml';
var time;
var times = new Array();
```

What will be available/set in Scene 2 - Layer 1?
Do I need to import mx.xpath.XPathAPI in each scene I want to use XPath?

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing this on the timeline, you will to use the `import` statement on each keyframe that references your class. so, forget scenes, you have to add your imports to each required keyframe :)